# DAX Running Total Add Previous Row

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

Is there a way to calculate the running Total that adds previous row value and dynamically resets the value like you would in standard excel?

[image]

This correctly calculates the running total:

```
RunningTotal =CALCULATE(SUMX('Table',[Notional]),FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[Column]),Table[Column]<=MAX(Table[Column])))
```

However, the calculation needs to be performed on each row so that another calculated measure, which will be dependent on the 'RunningTotal', can be accessed without creating a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a double [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powerquery-m/table-addindexcolumn) (one starting from 0 and the other from 1) and joining your table/query to itself.

Try this :

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}, {"Category", type text}, {"Volumne", Int64.Type}, {"InitialPrice", Int64.Type}, {"Notional", type number}, {"RunningTotal", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index0", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Index", "Index1", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index1", {"Index0"}, #"Added Index1", {"Index1"}, "Added Index1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Index1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Index1", {"Volumne", "RunningTotal"}, {"Index1.Volumne", "Index1.RunningTotal"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Added Index1", "Custom_RunningTotal", each if [Index0] = 0 then [RunningTotal] else [Index1.RunningTotal] + [Volumne]),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date", "Category", "Volumne", "InitialPrice", "Notional", "RunningTotal", "Custom_RunningTotal", "Index0", "Index1", "Index1.Volumne", "Index1.RunningTotal"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Index0", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index0", "Index1", "Index1.Volumne", "Index1.RunningTotal"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

I don't see what's in G3, So I put 1 as an original value.

[image]

Comment: appreciate the response.  RunningTotal column is not in my data.  Working with around 12k rows so setting indexes and calculating running totals to get to RunningTotal in my data model doesnt seem like good solution.  Custom_RunningTotal column above would need to be able to retain the value calculated in row 2 and then use it in row 3.